# Alphabetically order in python of a string

Tags: python, alphabetical

I understand there is sort() function, but it won't work for me here. I would like to order alphabetically a string like follows:

```
'S  NOM  V  NOUN  VERB'
```

It should be:

```
'NOM NOUN S VERB V'
```

How can I achieve that in python?

Edit:

I have tried:

```
''.join(sorted(m[i][j]))
```

But this returned with very changed output like `ABEILMNNNNOOPRSUVV` for example which doesn't make sense.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: split-sort-join

Comment: @idjaw, I already said what I have tried

Comment: @JohnColeman, how this is possible?

Comment: Why won't `sort` work for you here? If `sort` won't work for you, then surely you must have tried to see how you can do this without sort? Can you show *that* attempt?

Comment: Where did you say what you've tried? All I see is a mention of what you _didn't_ try (`sorted`), but should have, because it's part of what you need here.

Comment: maybe `sort()` doesn't work for you because it sorts "in-place" (change oryginal list) and doesn't return new list.

Comment: Also, what exactly are you trying to sort on? Because V should come before VERB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
x = 'S  NOM  V  NOUN  VERB'
x = x.split()   # produces ['S', 'NOM', 'V', 'NOUN', 'VERB']
x = sorted(x)   # produces ['NOM', 'NOUN', 'S', 'V', 'VERB']
x = ' '.join(x) # produces 'NOM NOUN S V VERB'
```

You will have to use a custom sorting function if you want the order of V and VERB to be reversed (see the 'key' keyword for the `sorted` function).

Comment: using sorted is the key here I think!

Answer (score 4):

You already have at least one good answer. You might as well abstract it into a function:

```
def sortWords(s, delim = ' '):
    return delim.join(sorted(s.split(delim)))
```

For example,

```
>>> sortWords('S NOM V NOUN VERB')
'NOM NOUN S V VERB'
```

Answer (score -1):

You should split the string into a list then sort it and turn it back into a string. Here is an example.

```
old_string = "hello world abc"
string_list = old_string.split(" ") # split the string by a space, you can choose something different.
new_string = " ".join(string_list.sort()) # join list by a space.
print(new_string)
```

Comment: it doesn't work because `sort()` works "in-place'. It change original list and doesn't return new one.

Comment: Using sorted, and not sort()